# node js DELETE author and GET books to show all books with info

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

First time trying node and express. The example I have use get and post, I would need to introduce DELETE to delete a book based on the title and I'm another GET in order to display all books when "localhost:3000/books" is typed.

This is what I have so far

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { fstat } = require('fs');

// adding a body parser to handle JSON and url encoded form data for us automagically
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// our in-memory fake data store is just an array of javascript objects
var books = [
    { "author": "me", "title": "BookA", "pages": 600, "quality": "new" },
    { "author": "you", "title": "BookB", "pages": 400, "quality": "used" },
    { "author": "us", "title": "BookC", "pages": 500, "quality": "old" },
];

// request handler to search based on two fields: author and title
app.get('/book', function (req, res) {
    // get the query params
    var title = req.query.title;

    // initialize the return data
    var data;

    // search for the book
    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        if (books[i].title == title) {
            data = books[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    // pass JSON back to client
    res.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    res.status(200);
    res.send({"book": data});
});

// post handler to add a book to the hardcoded list
// this is definitely not the correct model for storing data
// this is simply an example
app.post('/book', function (req, res) {
    // access the request POST body from the request object
    var data = req.body.data;

    // add the new book to the data store and return it
    var book = {
        "author": req.body.author,
        "title": req.body.title,
        "pages": req.body.pages,
        "quality": req.body.quality,
    }

    // add the book to the hardcoded list of books
    books.push(book);

    // return JSON list of books
    res.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    res.status(201);
    res.send({"books": books});
});

// listen for HTTP requests on port 3000
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("listening on port 3000");
});
```

I have this for DELETE just not sure if it'll work. I'm still playing around with POSTMAN at the moment

```
    // delete
app.delete('/delete/:booke', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.book;
    fstat.readFile("./book.json", 'utf8', (err,data) => {
        data = JSON.parse( data );

        delete data["book" + title];

        console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
        res.status(200);

        return res.send("Book removed");
    });
})
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Typo in your req parameter, it's book and not booke

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `delete` keyword for an Array, it will just empty the element while retaining the same array length.

Moreover, you want to delete from `books`, not `data`.

If the `booke` URL segment (in which you have a typo) is supposed to contain the index to delete, the code is:

```
books.splice(id, 1);
```